# Dataflow logs from Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-stackdriver

The **resource.labels.region** field for the dataflow_step logs in stackdriver, points to global even though the specified regional endpoint is Europe-west2.

Any idea on what is it exactly pointing to?

Comment: Do you see "global" on all logs for the job, or just some?

Comment: @Shalanki Gupta - can you comment if your question has been answered?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've supplied GCP [Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-viewer-preview) with the desired filtering option, as most simple query based on your inputs seeking for `dataflow_step` [resource type](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types):

```
resource.type="dataflow_step"
resource.labels.region="europe-west2"
```

You would probably observe query results retrieved from [Cloud Dataflow REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest), consisting with logs entries formatted as a JSON outputs for all Dataflow Jobs that are residing within your GCP project in `europe-west2` [Regional endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints):

```
{
  "insertId": "insertId",
  "jsonPayload": {
    ....
    "message": "Message content",
    ....
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "dataflow_step",
    "labels": {
      "job_id": "job_id",
      "region": "europe-west2",
      "job_name": "job_name",
      "project_id": "project_id",
      "step_id": "step_id"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "timestamp",
  "severity": "severity_level",
  "labels": {
    "compute.googleapis.com/resource_id": "resource_id",
    "dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id": "job_id",
    "compute.googleapis.com/resource_type": "resource_type",
    "compute.googleapis.com/resource_name": "resource_name",
    "dataflow.googleapis.com/region": "europe-west2",
    "dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name": "job_name"
  },
  "logName": "logName",
  "receiveTimestamp": "receiveTimestamp"
```

According to GCP logging service [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-indexes) each monitoring resource type derives particular labels from the nested service API, `dataflow.googleapis.com` corresponds to Dataflow service.

Therefore, if you run Dataflow Job defining the location for job's metadata `region`, GCP logging service will fetch up this regional endpoint from job description throughout `dataflow.googleapis.com` REST methods.

Answer (score 0):

The resource.labels.region field on Dataflow Step logs should refer to the regional endpoint that the job is using.  "Global" is not an expected value there.